# Wordpress hook that will instantiate a class to be able to use get_post_types before publish_CPT hook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I have an issue where I need to instantiate a class in wordpress so that in the constructor I can use the function get_post_types and have that hook happen before the publish_post hook (which I assume is around the publish_CPT hooks).

Here is the code I have so far

```
class Transient_Delete {

    /**
     * @var array of all the different post types on the site
     */
    private $postTypes;
    /**
     * @var array of wordpress hooks we will have to assemble to delete all possible transients
     */
    private $wpHooks;

    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postTypes = array_values( get_post_types(array(), 'names', 'and') );
        $this->wpHooks = $this->setWpHooks($this->postTypes);
        add_action('publish_alert', array($this, 'deleteAlertTest'));
    }

    private function setWpHooks($postTypes)
    {
        $hooks = array_map(function($postType) {
            return 'publish_' . $postType;
        }, $postTypes);

        return $hooks;
    }

    private function deleteAlertTest($post)
    {
        $postId = $post->ID;
        echo 'test';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'Transient_Delete', 'init' ));
```

Another note here is that this is in the mu-plugins directory.

note: "alert" of publish_alert is a custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was my fault, it looks like the hook publish_alert works fine if I change the deleteAlertTest function to public. Any idea on why having it be a private function has that effect? Its within the same class.

Comment: When you hook an action, the function passed to it is called directly without any reference. In case of the function being a private function inside a class, it cannot be identified by the executing action. You need to call deleteAlertTest with an object reference. Alternatively, you can hook a pubilc function available everywhere and then call this private function through an object reference inside that function.